# Laravel edit password reminders behaviour (not delete the row on password change)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, ioc-container

I want to change the way my password reminders behave. In Laravel, once a user resets their password, the row created in the password_reminders table with their token gets deleted.
I want to be able to do other things (set it to used, etc).
What I want to know is how to extend that behaviour.

The method reset in PasswordBroker is as follow: (Illuminate/Auth/reminders/PasswordBroker.php)

```
public function reset(array $credentials, Closure $callback)
{
    // If the responses from the validate method is not a user instance, we will
    // assume that it is a redirect and simply return it from this method and
    // the user is properly redirected having an error message on the post.
    $user = $this->validateReset($credentials);

    if ( ! $user instanceof RemindableInterface)
    {
        return $user;
    }

    $pass = $credentials['password'];

    // Once we have called this callback, we will remove this token row from the
    // table and return the response from this callback so the user gets sent
    // to the destination given by the developers from the callback return.
    call_user_func($callback, $user, $pass);

    $this->reminders->delete($credentials['token']);

    return self::PASSWORD_RESET;
}
```

Now in my RemindersController I am actullay calling the facade Password :

```
$response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
        {
            $user->password = Hash::make($password);

            $user->save();
        });
```

How do I create an extension of PasswordBroker and call it from my controller? DO I have to create a new Service Provider as well?
so write a new class that extends PasswordBroker, write a new Service provider that extends ReminderServiceProvider as well as a new Facade and call that new method of that new Facade in my controller ? Is that the proper way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Service providers and facades are just tools that allows class/object access on an Application level - that means in a application global scope.
In your case it depends from where and in which situations you want to have 
access to you extended class. In lot of cases namespacing is a better choice.
For example, you are already extending Laravel builtin class when creating new controller (your controller extends base controller ) but you are not creating new provider and facade for that class.

**Update (how to create new service provider):**

first create new folder under **app/** with your provider name (I usually place my providers under **app/services**)
then register that providers namespace in composer.json

next create three files:

1. base class file
2. provider class file
3. facade class file

plus helpers file if you have one.

Declare and define everything, composer dump-autoload and you'll have your provider.

Comment: so you reckon creating a class that extends passwordbroker.php, have a reset method and call that extended class/method through namespacing driectly? No need to go through Facades ? It would be nice to have it available on a app-wide level though, so how would I go about doing that? create that class and bot a service provider and a facade for it?

Comment: Looks easy when explained like that! I'll give it a crack cheers.